# How to source or activate a virtual environment within an IPython shell?

Tags: python, ipython, virtualenv, pipenv, python-poetry

I use IPython and the `%bookmark` magic command but the limitation is that I need to exit the IPython shell to activate a virtual environment and then relaunch IPython.

Is there a way, built into IPython, a third-party package, or a known hack to let me activate the environment without exiting the IPython shell?

### Actual workflow

```sh
# within ipython shell
exit

# bash shell
cd path/of/my/project
poetry shell  # or pipenv shell
ipython
```

### Intended workflow

```py
%cd -b demographics

# activate venv 

import package # from that env
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question, but unfortunately, the answer might not be what you are hoping for. If I understood your question correctly - this is not possible. Because virtual shell activation is essentially running child process that setups PATH for another Python interpreter and then PYTHONPATH environment variable for this. A child process can never modify its parent process in any operating system. You cannot, for example, change the Python interpreter you already have running because replacing a running process in-memory is super complicated and never done in practice.

If this is a workflow issue and you *definitely* want to do this from within IPython, I suggest you write an one-liner copy paste command that would do something along these lines:

- Launches a new IPython using the virtualenv e.g. `(source venv/bin/activate && ipython)`
- Terminates the old, existing IPython session that has been launched from the virtualenv (though not sure how you can exit IPython within IPython prompt)

There is likely a better solution for his workflow question. Maybe there is a workflow that is similar as `%%bookmark`, but for the whole Python environments and processes, like creating shell scripts.

Comment: "*not sure how you can exit IPython within IPython prompt*" Not sure what you mean here, but `exit()` or `quit()` closes the IPython shell. But they have to be called from within the IPython shell. So it's quite impossible to integrate with a script or a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround and essentially activate the virtualenv from python. This hack is dependent on the location of activate_this.py
I've tested it on virtualenv version 20.2.1, might not work with different versions.

*Not recommended for Production*

Try this:

```
import virtualenv
import os
import sys

# Provide the location of your venv
venv_loc = r'C:\work\test-venv'

# Setup a new virtual env, if not setup already.
# Skip this line if you want to use an existing virtual env
virtualenv.run.cli_run([venv_loc])

# Find activator script. This is only tested in virtualenv version 20.2.1
if str(os.name).lower() == "nt":
    venv_activator = os.path.join(venv_loc, 'Scripts', 'activate_this.py')
elif str(os.name).lower() == "posix":
    venv_activator = os.path.join(venv_loc, 'bin', 'activate_this.py')
else:
    print("unsupported OS")
    sys.exit(1)

# Activate virtual env
exec(open(venv_activator).read(), {'__file__': venv_activator})

# Now you can import your package.
```

Comment: Have you tested running this from _within an IPython shell_ that was launched _from an already activated virtual env_?

Comment: Yes, I have tested that.

Comment: Hmmm.. it doesn't seem to work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSsvK.png. Here in my screenshot, I have 2 virtual envs, `someproject` and `scratch3.8`. I have your script on `scratch3.8` and the goal is to run your script to activate the venv in `someproject`. Even after running your script, it did not activate the target venv correctly (could not import the package installed on that venv). I'm doing all this inside an IPython shell since the OP's workflow is using IPython.

Comment: Also tried running your script from outside an IPython shell, then reopening IPython after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC5iM.png. It still did not import the package from the 1st someproject env correctly. Note that for both tests, I have IPython launched from an *already activate virtual env* (same as the OP's workflow)

Comment: I dont think you can run it as a script, as the shell would change. I would suggest to copy paste that code in the ipython shell to activate the environment.
Also can you please share what version of virtualenv you are using?
Does it have the activate_this.py at the same location that's being used in the code I shared above?

Comment: I'm using virtualenv installed with pipenv (pretty much all package managers use virtualenv internally). And yes, it has the `activate_this.py` in `/path/to/venv/bin`, so your path for `posix` is correct. I'll try copy-pasting the python code instead of runniing the script (although I feel like that would be inconvenient to do every time...).